# Blind: Looking for solution to sync audio described MP3 with movie from other source to not disturb others

Tags: iphone, audio, software-recommendation, appletv

I'm new here so I hope I get this right...

I'm blind and am looking for a way of syncing up an mp3 downloaded from:

http://www.audiovault.net

which has the audio described tracks taken from movies, with the specific movie. For example, I could get the MP3 of Back To The Future which is the full audio track with audio description included, and then go to my Apple TV app where I have purchased the film. I would turn the film on and load up the mp3 on my iPhone, using this mystery app, and by doing a sound wave comparison, the MP3 on the phone is magically synced with the movie...

Big ask I know.

Spectrum do an app called spectrum access:

https://acb.org/adp/spectrumad.html

that does this, though I'm not sure what magic is going on in the background as they are supplied with the audio described tracks by the movie studios. Sadly their offering is US only and is somewhat limited.

In combination with the extensive library at [www.audiovault.net](http://www.audiovault.net) and this mystery app, it could unlock watching films with friends and family for the blind. I hate watching things with audio description on if I'm with sighted company as it's annoying for everyone, but without it, I miss out. This could be a great leveller.

Comment: Interesting app/programming challenge.  I would think that there are ways to do it, but it seems easier to just press "play" at the same time (if watching from the beginning).  Also, any programming written to use that particular site is risky.  They are clearly in violation of copyright laws by posting descriptive-audio tracks taken from published works.  I don't know how feasible it would be, but the community could benefit from an open-source library of descriptive-audio that you could, say, play in one ear, while listening to the original audio playing in the room with the other ear.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. The issue with playing at the same time is that the audio described track also has the main audio track of the movie on it causing a very distracting delay if not synced up correctly, hence the request.

Comment: The issue with playing at the same time is that the audio described track also has the main audio track of the movie on it causing a distracting delay if not synced up correctly, hence the request. No guilt for a minority sharing described content, most of which is available on services that we already pay for. :) Let me revise, maybe a sync app is a bit difficult, maybe a MP3 player app with tighter skip granularity could be employed... Trouble is, I can't find one.